# (g)vim replace regex

Tags: regex, vim

I'm looking for a regex that will change sth. like this:

```
print "testcode $testvar \n";
```

in

`printnlog("testcode $testvar \n");`

I tried `%s/print\s*(.\{-});/printnlog(\1);/g` but gvim says

```
print\s*(.\{-});
```

doesn't match.

Where is my fault?
Is it ok to use '*' after '\s' because later '{-};' will stop the greed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1. for `{-}`, I forgot about that in Vim

Comment: Found a nice site for regex in vim -> http://vimregex.com 
enjoy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In vim you have to prepend `(`, `)` and `|` with backslash, so try

```
:%s/print\s*\(.\{-}\);/printnlog(\1);/g
```

Comment: can't believe I forgot to escape the brackets :) your regex works perfectly fine

Comment: Thanks MBO, deleted the original and fixed it below!

Comment: Unless you use `\v`, then you don't have to escape everything - http://briancarper.net/blog/vim-regexes-are-awesome

Comment: +1 for \v, it will save (me) a lot of backslashes in the future

Answer (score 4):

MBO's answer works great, but sometimes I find it easier to use the "very magic" option `\v` so I don't have to escape everything; makes the regex a little more readable.

See also:

- `:h /\v` in Vim
- http://briancarper.net/blog/vim-regexes-are-awesome

Comment: Great, I was searching for such feature.

Comment: voted up your comment above, because I agree, it increases readability and saves you some time

Answer (score 0):

While you can create capture groups (like you're doing), I think the easiest approach is to do the job in multiple steps, with very simple regexes and "flag" words. For example:

```
:%s/print "testcode.*/printnlog(XXX&XXX);/
:%s/XXXprint //
:%s/;XXX//
```

In these examples, I use "XXX" to indicate boundaries that should later be trimmed (you can use anything that doesn't appear in your code). The ampersand (&) takes the entire match string and inserts it into the replacement string.

I don't know about other people, but I can type and execute these three regexes faster than I can think through a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Is this sufficient for your needs?

```
%s/print\s*\("[^"]*"\)/printnlog(\1)
```

Comment: this regex is ok also, but I already marked another answer as "accepted", not only because it was the first working regex, but it remembers to escape brackets in vim :)