# How to change var[foo] to foo using Vim substitution?

Tags: vim

Today I came across this situation where I need to change `var[name]` to `var [name]` and a lot of other place where `name` could be description or other string. Can I do something like the following command:

```
%s/var[$variable]/$variable/g
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? Do you have some example input and output? (Yes this can be done but probably not with what you have written)

Comment: Are you working with the literal `$variable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the title of the question, the following expression should change `var[foo]` to `foo`:

```
:%s/\vvar\[(.{-})\]/\1/g
```

But in the details you mentioned that you need to change `var[name]` to `var [name]`, following should do that:

```
:%s/\v(var)(\[.{-}\])/\1 \2/g
```

Other ways of doing the second substitution from comments:

```
:%s/var\zs\ze\[.*\]/ /g
```

or

```
:%s/var\zs\ze\[[^]]*\]/ /g
```

Comment: Thanks, the first line works for me, So does `\1` refer to what match inside the `()`, am I correct?

Comment: Great! Yes `\1` refers to first capture group.

Comment: Beware of greedy modifiers, especially `.*`.  The first command in this answer replaces `var[foo] var[bar]` with `foo] var[bar`, and the second replaces it with `var [foo] var[bar]`.  Try using `.\{-}` or `[^]]*`.

Comment: Reduce the number of backslashes with the "very magic" modifier:  `:%s/\v(var)(\[.{-}\])/\1 \2/g`.

Comment: Vim golf for the second substitution: `:%s/var\zs\ze\[.*\]/ /g` or `:%s/var\zs\ze\[[^]]*\]/ /g` (less greedy)

Comment: @Amit, please update your answer with some of the suggestions above (mine and Peter Rincker's).

Comment: @benjifisher - Sure, I will try them out and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Related: [(g)vim replace regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847240/gvim-replace-regex)

The thing to know, if you already know about regex and captures in general, is in this context you apparently have to escape the group characters, rather than it being the other way around:

```
%s/var[\(variable\)]/\1/g
```

Without more info, I can't be more helpful.

Comment: You probably want to escape the character class. Otherwise this isn't doing what you expect it to do...